# Error compiling gcc-4.5.2

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, compilation

I'm trying to compile gcc 4.5.2 on mac os x 10.6.6 with the following configure command:

```
../gcc-452a/configure --prefix=/builds/dist1/gcc/452a --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,fortran --with-pkgversion='Builds, build 452a'
```

It compiles fine (make -j3) up to a certain part, but then it says:

```
checking for working strncmp... yes
configure: updating cache ./config.cache
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating testsuite/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing default commands
Adding multilib support to Makefile in ../../../../gcc-452a/libiberty
with_multisubdir=i386
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please help

If it makes any difference "current_stage" = stage3

Comment: Before you try anything else, fix the space after the comma in `--with-pkgversion=Builds, build 452a`, by removing or quoting it.

Comment: Doesn't look like anyone can help :S

Comment: Daniel, you should check the logs for specific error. Also, I recommend you to do a `make -j1` build - with such setting, the specific error will be just before `*** [all] Error 2`.

Comment: Edit your question and paste the last few lines in config.log. Don’t forget to follow @osgx’s `-j1` suggestion.

Comment: Don't have a 10.6.6 machine handy, but trying on 10.6.7 I couldn't reproduce this. If provide the config.log information from the subdirectory the error happens in as mentioned by others, someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need multilib support from your GCC, so you could configure it with `--disable-multilib`